# How Can I Customize Login Page for Oauth2 in Spring Webflux?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I just want to override default oauth2 login url (`/login`). How can I do that? The config I have tried without success:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
                .authorizeExchange().pathMatchers(permittedUrls).permitAll()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults()).formLogin().loginPage("/oauth2_login")
                .authenticationSuccessHandler(this::onAuthenticationSuccess)
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
```

I was hoping it will redirect to `/oauth2_login` url but it didn't work. It still redirect to /login. But this time it returns 404 instead of showing default login page.

Answer (score -1):

The code above is customizing the login page for `formLogin` which is typically username/password based log in from a form. It's much easier to see what configuration you are impacting using the new lambda style approach, so I have updated the entire configuration to use it. If you want to customize the login page for oauth2Login, then you should change the login page on it. For example:

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http
            .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges
                .pathMatchers(permittedUrls).permitAll()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2
                // you now must render a log in page for the URL /login
                .loginPage("/login") 
            );
            // remove formLogin that was for a username/password based log in
            // if you are doing oauth2 login I'm guessing you allow users to work within a browser, so you should not disable csrf
    return http.build();
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer but it didn't compiled. (Cannot resolve method 'loginPage' in 'OAuth2LoginSpec')