# Customizing login page for OAUTH2 login with Spring Webflux

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-gateway

I am looking to customize my oauth2 login page. I am using Spring cloud Gateway so this is Spring Security Webflux. This should be fairly straightforward but I cannot figure out a way to do it with Webflux security. Stuff I have tried :

- I have tried using loginPage() as suggested in
  [How Can I Customize Login Page for Oauth2 in Spring Webflux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64833725/how-can-i-customize-login-page-for-oauth2-in-spring-webflux)
  but as the O.P. posted there, this does not compile in the webflux
  world.
- I have tried putting in a controller at /login and have it direct to
  my custom page but the controller is not hit.
  My SecurityConfig :

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain configure(ServerHttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf().disable().authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/oauth2login",
                        "*/*.js", "/*.json", "/*.ico", "/login").permitAll()
                .pathMatchers("/api/","/api/**").authenticated()
                .and().oauth2ResourceServer(ServerHttpSecurity.OAuth2ResourceServerSpec::jwt)
                .authorizeExchange().anyExchange().authenticated()
               .and().securityContextRepository(new WebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository())
                   .oauth2Login()
                .and().build();
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bit confusing because there are multiple different ways to customize the login page depending on what type of authentication you are configuring in servlet-based applications.

In reactive applications, it has been centralized in one place (`exceptionHandling()` in the DSL), so you can simply set the authentication entry point as in the following example:

```java
.exceptionHandling(exceptions -> exceptions
        .authenticationEntryPoint(new RedirectServerAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"))
)
```

This disables the default login page, and you just need to provide your own which should match the configured URL.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I would not have thought of having it centralized in exceptionHandling() on my own.

Comment: Yeah, I missed it in my first project as well. :)

Comment: lovely! I've spent far too much time on this. thank you a bunch

Comment: @VibhaGopal, Good evening! Could you please send me the whole code snippet? I'm also trying to make webflux and oauth2 friends

Comment: You can start with the example in the docs: [Register a SecurityWebFilterChain @Bean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/login/core.html#webflux-oauth2-login-register-securitywebfilterchain-bean)